# Remove italics from APA6 documentclass references

Tags: apa6

I am writing something using the APA6 documentclass, but for the draft manuscript, it is specified that references should be in APA format but without italics. Is there a work around so that no italics appears in the References section using APA6? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `apa6` class is agnostic as to how your references are formatted; this is done by either the `apacite` or `biblatex-apa` bibliography packages. See [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/263800) Which one are you using?

Comment: Also, this requirement seems quite odd, given the following link from the APA website: https://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/resources/manuscript-submission-guidelines.  Where did you find this requirement?